# how to gain more privileges in google oauth?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, oauth

Basically i have using `Google-oauth` in my website, but so far i know is getBasicProfile()but i need more, in my website i want these google users to be able to purchase items with their google card from my website so to gain that kind of privileges what do he have?

here is my google oauth button creation code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="921258372597-t5jrb0e9p4ivstp9mfi972lhcvfcuo59.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<script>
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
  console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
  console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
  console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span><h1>google sign in Button</h1></span>
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Google had a product called "Google Wallet for digital goods", and another product called "instant buy for physical goods", [both these products were deprecated](https://support.google.com/payments/merchant/answer/6107573?hl=en).

Now the only options for using Google to process purchases for your business is using [Android Pay](https://www.android.com/pay/), which is only available on mobile for Android Apps.

Google doesn't offer a product that allows you to process payments through javascript. For that use case I suggest you look for another solution. Some popular ones are Stripe and BrainTree.